# question about range, quotient space and bounded linear operator

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose that $T$ is a bounded linear operator and let $N(T)$ and $R(T)$ be its kernel and range, respectively, and define $\tilde{T}$ be the induced one-to-one operator  from the quotient space $X/N(T)$ into $Y$:
\begin{equation}\tilde{T}(f+N(T))=Tf,\quad f\in X/N(T)\end{equation}
and let $\tilde{T}^{-1}:R(T)\rightarrow X/N(T)$ be the inverse of $\tilde{T}$ with the norm
\begin{equation*} ||\tilde{T}^{-1}||=\sup_{\begin{subarray}{l}
                             ||f||\le 1   \\
                             f\in R(T)
        \end{subarray}}\inf_{h\in N(T)}||\tilde{T}^{-1}(f)+h||.\end{equation*}

Prove that the following statements are equivalent:

(i)$R(T)$ is closed;

(ii)$\tilde{T}^{-1}$ is bounded.

hint: somebody tell me that it has connection with the open mapping theorem.

Comment: Are $X$ and $Y$ assumed to be Banach spaces?

Comment: YES，both are banach spaces

Answer (score 2):

> hint: somebody tell me that it has connection with the open mapping theorem.

Indeed. Since $X$ is a Banach space, and $T$ is continuous, $Q := X/N(T)$ is a Banach space too.

So we have a continuous bijection

$$\tilde{T}\colon Q \to R(T).$$

Now one direction of

$$R(T)\text{ closed} \iff \lVert \tilde{T}^{-1}\rVert < \infty$$

is part of the open mapping theorem: if $R(T)$ is closed, then $\tilde{T}$ is a continuous bijection of Banach spaces. By the open mapping theorem $\tilde{T}$ is an open mapping (viewed as a mapping to $R(T)$), hence its inverse $\tilde{T}^{-1}$ is continuous, i.e. bounded. The other direction uses the fact that complete subspaces are closed: if $\tilde{T}^{-1}$ is continuous (bounded), then $\tilde{T}$ is a bi-Lipschitz map $Q\to R(T)$, and hence $R(T)$ is complete.